# How to increase Flex Mobile performance with GPU render mode?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, air, retina-display

I'm developing an app with Flex and Air (Mobile) and the Flash Builder and, despite some other problems I had, the most worrying issue for me right now is that I need to embed a SWF Flash animation into the interface. The app must run in a Retina Display iPhone 4 so I turned the GPU render mode on, in order to gain some performance in the "Flex part". It works very well (I've got a better performance rendering big resolution assets rather than using CPU mode) but the problem comes with the "embeded Flash part", which is showing nice in CPU mode but very slow and with some vector artifacts in GPU.

From my limited skills (I'm relatively new to Flex) I think having the option to switch between rendering modes at runtime would be the perfect solution (I mean GPU for the menus and overall Flex interface, and CPU for the embedded vectorial movie) but I've been told this is not possible by now.

Is it true? Is there any other way to achieve it and make the two parts run correctly and fluently? Why the GPU mode is making the Flash movie so painful?

Thank you very much for advance!

Comment: That is true, you can't switch render modes at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that Flex isn't developed to run on the GPU. As such you aren't really gaining anything by putting the application in GPU Mode. If you are REALLY wanting to run on the GPU you may want to look at feathersui.com and try that. Other than that I would leave your application's mode as "auto".